# How to copy the first Character of a Label with a button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, copy

I have a label that I want to only copy the first character. The label reads 1000. I have my copy button set up like this

```
var textCopy = label.Text;
Clipboard.SetText(textCopy);
```

Can I add something to the label.Text part that only allows the first character to be copied?

Comment: just use `Substring`

Answer (score 0):

string is an array of characters, so just get the first index of the string like this:

```
Clipboard.SetText(textCopy[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Substring`:

```
var textCopy = label.Text;
Clipboard.SetText(textCopy.Substring(0,1));
```

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)